# NameError: name 'np' is not defined in flask API

Tags: python, numpy, rest, flask

I'm working with flask API and I have installed numpy module but when I try to call the file with flask API in postman it's giving error NameError: name 'np' is not defined in flask API but on the other side when I'm directly running that file in pycharm it's working fine. I have tried :

```
import numpy as np
import numpy
from numpy import *
```

invalidate cache & restart

uninstalled/install python and pycharm

Using python 3.9

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 8, in calibration_func
    exec(open("calibration.py").read())
  File "<string>", line 117, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 32, in initial_calibration
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Note: The called file that has numpy used to run ~20 minutes

Comment: If you have your first line in your code and you did not delete `np` from the namespace explicitly, you should not get that name error. Please show us a [minimal reproducible examply](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including the full error traceback.

Comment: @KlausD. minimal flask app is running fine with numpy.  But not running with project.

Comment: The error is in your `calibration.py`. And BTW using `exec()` is considered bad practice.

Comment: @KlausD. calibration.py is working fine when I try to run it alone or from exec(open("calibration.py").read()). Only error is occurring when calling it from API.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in this line:

```
from numpy import *
```

This is a bad practice to import everything from module:

```
from <module> import *
```

Better to import only necessary methods or module itself.

You need only this line:

```
import numpy as np
```

Comment: I have already tried that.